# Datepicker is hidding under a boostrap modal

Tags: html, css, forms, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal tag that displays a form when a button is click. The form contains a datepicker but it shows beneath the modal tag. How should i go about it. The modal has z-index to 1025

Comment: We can't help you unless you post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in one of my project. try this once

```
.datepicker{z-index:9999 !important}
```

Ref:- [Github](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1129)